# Rubik's cube rotation

Tags: c++, opengl

I created a rubik's cube with 26 squares(not 27 since you cant see the middle one). I am trying to rotate the cube. I thought about using Pushstack Popstack, but I couldnt find any good examples I could look at.

I was wondering what is a good way to rotate. I used 26 of the following code to create the cubes

```
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  //glColor3f(  1.0,  0.0,  1.0 );
  glColor3f(   1.0,  0.0,  0.0 );
  glVertex3f( 1.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
  glVertex3f( 1.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
  glVertex3f( 1.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
  glVertex3f( 1.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
  glEnd();
```

Comment: Without showing some of your code you could also go and ask _all-knowing, all-seeing Trash Heap_.

Comment: What is your data structure (specifically)?  This determines the algorithms.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I edited the initial question. Also any other way you would suggest I create the cubes

Answer (score 2):

Your code produces a face, not a whole cube. But you will need 26 complete small cubes in order to render it correctly. Otherwise, if you rotate a cube, there will be holes.

You can do something like the following:

Organize the big cube as a 3x3x3 grid. Each grid cell contains a small cube. Each small cube consists of its geometry data and its rotation information. You can store the geometry data as a vertex buffer or as a display list or as a method that generates the geometry on the fly. Just as you wish. So if you don't have any rotations yet and you render the pure geometry, you should get the whole cube well-aligned.

For the rotations it is reasonable to use a quaternion for each small cube. However, you could use matrices as well, but those are a bit trickier to handle. Actually, I would store two quaternions for each cube. One that describes the target rotation and one that describes the current rotation (for animation purposes). When updating the current rotation towards the target rotation, you can do something like this:

```
interpolationVariable = c ^ timeStep //to allow a fluid and continuous animation. 
//c is usually between 0.99 and 1, depending on the desired animation smoothness
currentRotation := interpolationVariable  * currentRotation + (1 - interpolationVariable ) * targetRotation
currentRotation.normalize()
```

This is actually an infinite adjustment. You should introduce a threshold for the difference of `currentRotation` and `targetRotation` to set `currentRotation` to `targetRotation` and update only if `currentRotation != targetRotation`.

Now we have the rotation specified as a quaternion. In order to render the cube, you can apply the quaternion as a model transformation (after the conversion to a matrix) and render the geometry.

To rotate a cube slice, you simply have to apply a rotation transformation to the according cubes. E.g. if you want to rotate about the x-axis:

```
quat = QuaternionRotation( (1,0,0) /* axis */ , Pi / 2 /* angle */ )
for each affected cube
    cube.targetRotation = cube.targetRotation * quat
next    
// Update the grid
```

And the slice will rotate nicely to the target position. If you have the geometry well-alignes (around the origin), you don't need any translation because all rotations will be about the origin (or an axis through the origin).

Comment: I'm not really familiar with quarternions. Can I use push stack pop stack?

Comment: A single stack won't help you because you have different rotations for each small cube. In most libraries there is already a quaternion implementation, so you just have to use it.